# Remove error from main.xml file in menu

Tags: android

I've been getting an error in main.xml file which is in menu folder. R.java isn't generated. The error is on the last line of xml code. I have tried everything...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: You should show your error

Answer (score 2):

Put this line in `strings.xml` inside `/res/values` directory

```
 <string name="action_settings">Your String Here</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, if you know basic html, you should know that every tag has an opening tag and a closing tag. That being said, in your code, you close the item tag but you forgot to closs the menu tag :-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: There was a closing `menu` tag, but wasn't showing in the post because of missing indent in the code.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` Remove this line and error will be gone

Comment: then i would suggest your post the error from the error log

Answer (score 0):

Cut your code from your xml-file and paste it in an normal text editor, notepad or gedit or something like this. Copy it back to your xml-file. Sometimes this helps.

Comment: well d error goes bt it returns wen i run d program & my R.java is not generated..

Comment: Try to clean your project or restart eclipse

Comment: Perhaps you have to do this for all your xml-files